# HighCharts: how to draw a radar plot showing different scale labels on each axis?

Tags: highcharts, radar-chart

I need to plot a radar chart using HighCharts; in particular, all of the series have a different scale. I am able to draw correctly the radar chart using multiple scales (one per y-axis), but I see multiple overlapping labels on the main y-axis, which is clearly wrong. Now, I want instead to plot the labels related to every y-axis on the corresponding y-axis. How can I do this ?

Here is a snippet that can be pasted in jsFiddle to verify that the labels indeed overlap.

```
$(function () {
window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        polar: true,
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Indicators Radar Chart',
        x: -80
    },
    pane: {
        size: '90%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },
    yAxis: [{
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valuePrefix: ''
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Austria',
        yAxis: 0,
        data: [0.130435, 35.043480, 29288.695312, 236960.296875],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Germany',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [0.000000, 42.217392, 149103.906250, 589782.500000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Italy',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [2.304348, 44.826088, 132805.218750, 878785.937500],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
});
```

});

The output I am trying to obtain is such that for this particular chart, the labels related to the different scales appear along each axis: from the center point to A, from the center point to B, from the center point to C and from the center point to D. The problem is that right now all of the labels appear on the same axis, from the center point to A.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share a jsFiddle? Also an image of the end graph that you are looking for will help

Comment: @JugalThakkar, I have edited my question adding a code snippet that you can paste directly in jsFiddle (just add the scripts required for a radar chart and you're done); moreover, I have better explained what kind of result I am trying to achieve. Drawing an image will take me some time ( I am very bad at this), but if strictly required, I will try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/eyugex/edit

You seem to assume that each of the axes extend from the center to different directions, but this is not the case. All Y axes extend from the center. The X axis starts on top of the chart and follows the perimeter clockwise around the perimeter and ends on top. The Y axis labels are drawn where the X axis starts, which is up.

In a chart like this it wouldn't make sense to add multiple Y axes because they are all drawn on top of each other and you can't visually distinguish one from another.

Comment: I knew that labels overlap since are drawn on top of each other. The problem is that I actually need multiple Y axes, since each series needs a different scale. The HighCharts radar plot does an excellent job at drawing the chart; however, I need to draw charts like chart 2 appearing on http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/graham/2011/09/a-critique-of-radar-charts/ in which every axis has a different scale, and labels are drawn near the axes. The fact that HighCharts does not seem to provide this feature does not mean that it does not make sense ;-)

Comment: So, at least from my perspective, this feature is a welcomed addition to HighCharts. The richness of a library comes from the unusual features it provides, not from the usual options we all expect to see ;-)

Comment: Anyway, please update your answer stating explicitly that HighCharts does not allow what I asked for (may be it will in the next release?), and I will be glad to accept your answer as final. Thank you.